# ¿Como se llama la parte superior de un cerro?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, geografía

¿Como se llama la parte superior de un cerro? ¿Sería «cima» o «cumbre» o hay otro término?

Pregunto porque en inglés normalmente un término como «peak» o «summit» no se usa para los cerros. Son más asociados con montañas. ¿Es así tambien en castellano o no hay problema usando «cima» o «cumbre» para cerros?

Comment: En inglés cima sería "top" e igual que en inglés uno puede decir "the top of the hill" o "the top of the Everest" en español es válido decir "la cima del Everest" o "la cima de la colina o el cerro".  Igual con cumbre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En efecto, el significado de [*cima*](https://dle.rae.es/?w=cima) en el DLE dice:

> Punto más alto de los montes, cerros y collados.

Ahora bien, una [*cumbre*](https://dle.rae.es/cumbre?m=form) puede aplicar desde la 2.ª acepción:

> Mayor elevación de algo o máximo grado a que puede llegar.

Si bien la primera hace referencia al punto máximo de un monte, un cerro se define como una elevación menor que un monte, así que su mayor elevación sería su cumbre.

Answer (score 2):

Otros sinónimos, además de los ya dados en los mensajes anteriores, son [cúspide](https://dle.rae.es/c%C3%BAspide?m=form) y [copete](https://dle.rae.es/copete?m=form). En Panamá se usa también [curumba](https://dle.rae.es/?w=curumba).

> curumba
>   1. f. Pan. Parte más alta o cúspide de un cerro, un árbol o un tejado. El mango está en la curumba del árbol.

Comment: Esta respuesta aparece en las colas de revisión como "Low Quality" post (posiblemente debido a su brevedad) y corre el riesgo de ser eliminada. Creo que la respuesta ganaría mucho si la editases para añadir enlaces a las definiciones del diccionario de "cúspide y copete", pero en especial "curumba", puesto que en otros sitios no hemos oído nunca ese término. Aparte del enlace podrías copiar la definición. De lo contrario este aporte parece un simple comentario en lugar de intentar explicar algo apoyándose en referencias, que es lo que hacemos con las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

En Chile hay una expresión coloquial para decirle a alguien que deje de molestar, o que no se le hará caso alguno.... "Ándate a la **punta** del cerro", así que creo que **punta** sería otra opción.

También se usa en otros contextos:

> **Querer mandar todo a la punta del cerro**: Colapsar frente a las presiones laborales o emocionales es una expresión de penas, rabias o frustraciones guardadas durantes años.
>
> Fuente: Emol.com - https://www.emol.com/noticias/Tendencias/2011/06/17/735395/Querer-mandar-todo-a-la-punta-del-cerro.html

**Actualización**:
He recordado otra palabra que no hace referencia exacta a la **cima** de un cerro, pero que podría aplicarse: **cresta**.

El DRAE en su 4a acepción dice:

> 4. f. Cumbre de agudos peñascos de una montaña.